# Is $\sqrt{-(x^2)}$ discontinous on the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know this function does not exist on the reals, but does that mean it is discontinuous on the reals?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{-(x^2)}$?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it now. Apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain is $\{0 \}$, and the function is indeed continuous there. For any fixed $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Then it is true that $\forall x \in (-\delta, \delta): |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$, since the only $x$ there is to check is $x=0$, and at that point we have $|f(x)-0|=|0-0|=0<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered. This is would be like saying "If an object doesn't have a color, is it's color a shade of blue?".

The definition of "discontinuous on the reals" assumes that we have a function on the reals. If we do not have such a function, the definition doesn't make sense.

Comment: I guess what Jack is asking is whether the function is discontinuous {\it across} the reals: when tracking the function value as $x$ moves along the imaginary axis in the complex plane, the function switches from i$|x|$ to $-$i$|x|$. It is $0$ at $x=0$, so it is continuous (and exists in one real number)..